# Settings to remove words from document is not working for elasticsearch DSL query

Tags: python, elasticsearch, dsl

My dictionary is below, I have loaded the cluster

```
[
{'id':1,  'name': 'weather report', 'description': 'Today is cooler weather'},
{'id':2,  'name': 'weather report', 'description': 'Today is hotter weather'},
{'id':3,  'name': 'weather report', 'description': 'Today is warm weather'}
]
```

I loaded the cluster

```
for i in wea:
    es.index(index="wea", body=i, id=i['id'])
```

- I am searching for hot*
- I have stop words hotter
- so in the output there is no content

Below is the code

```
es.indices.close("wea")
settings = {
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "blogs_analyzer": {
          "type": "standard",
          "stopwords": [
            "hotter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "blogs_analyzer"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "blogs_analyzer"
      },
      "description": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "blogs_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
# es.indices.create(index="wea", ignore=400, body=settings)
es.indices.put_settings(index="wea", body=settings)
es.indices.open("wea")
```

- The above scenario is perfectly working fine. now the problem

If i am changing my stopwords from 'hotter' to 'cooler' and i am searching cool* then my output has to be empty.

but I am getting `{'id':3,  'name': 'weather report', 'description': 'Today is cooler weather'}`

I found one solution i have to reload the cluster? Is that correct approach? any way to achieve without reloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reloading the cluster, you can [close the index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-close.html) and use the [update index settings API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html) to update the analyzer configuration, then [reopen the index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-open-close.html).

You can use the below commands :

```
POST /<index-name>/_close

PUT /<index-name>/_settings
{
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "blogs_analyzer": {
                "type": "standard",
                "stopwords": [
                    "hotter",
                    "cooler"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}

POST /<index-name>/_open
```

**The updated stopwords would only apply to new or modified documents, not to existing documents.**

You must [reindex the documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) if you want to apply the modifications to the existing documents.

Comment: I am glad to say you are super in ES

Comment: where you find `You must reindex the documents if you want to apply the modifications to the existing documents.`

Comment: @sim Thanks for your kind words ;-) whenever you update the index settings, the new index setting will not automatically apply to the already existing documents. If you want to update the documents then you have to reindex the documents.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72964121/how-to-add-suggestion-inside-term-query-in-dsl